# Flex dynamic ComboBox via JSON

Tags: json, actionscript-3, mxml

I am new to AS and FLEX and am wondering how a dynamic load of ComboBox data can be achieved.
Presently I have the following code:

```
// ActionScript
public var staff:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(
[ {label:"Kim"}, 
{label:"Mike"}, 
{label:"Eric"} ]);

// MXML
<s:ComboBox dataProvider="{staff}"  id="employee_select" />


// from JSON
["Kim","Mike","Eric"]
```

I am getting a JSON string of  from a web service which populates it from a JAVA array and would like to populate the data provider from this source. Can someone help me out? I have looked for as3 tutorials but have not found this answer anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest updating the title to accurately reflect what your issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through as you would normally do.

see example:

```
var yourJASONobj:Object = {
    "riders": [
        {   "name": "Paul Waters",
            "age": "38",
            "spouse": "Shannon Elizabeth Colman",
            "email": "paul@dimain.com"
        }
    ]
};

var id_string:String = "Paul Waters";
for(var a:String in yourJASONobj.riders[0]) {
    var b:String = yourJASONobj.riders[0][a];
    if (b == id_string){
        trace(id_string + "'s spouse is " + yourJASONobj.riders[0].spouse)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
[Bindable]    
private var staff : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

public function setComboBoxProvider(jsonString : String) : void {
    // from JSON
    //["Kim","Mike","Eric"]       
    staff.source = JSON.parse();
}


// MXML
<s:ComboBox dataProvider="{staff}"  id="employee_select" />
```